# counting substring in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Python Infant here.
Trying to count no. of times 'jam' occur at the string "s".
The output is supposed to be 3 here, but I only see 1.What am I doing wrong here?

```
s='jamrejaminjam'
word ='jam'
count =0
for letters in s:
    if letters in word:
        count =+1
print(count)
```

Comment: Should be `+= 1`.

Comment: @vaultah doesn't work

Comment: `count =+1` does not do what you believe it does. It simply assigns `1` to count *every time*. As vaultah suggested, change it to `count += 1`. This won't find substrings though, it will just fix your `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Jim I get 9 instead of 3 when I changed  count+=1..

Comment: Yup, that isn't actually counting substrings, it's counting number of characters in `s` that happen to also be in `word`. use `s.count(word)` for a quick solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
s='jamrejaminjam'
word ='jam'
count =0
for index, letters in enumerate(s):
    if word == s[index:index+len(word)]:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with you. My snippet has only two changes from his original code. First is enumerate, and second is string slicing. Unless I have done something clever or hard to understand, it is the responsibility of those who want to learn to ask more questions. I assume you're in the software industry, and you know as well as I that those who need to be spoon-fed will not survive the industry. I provided some modest edits, and there are TONS of examples on Google and SO that explains how to use these. Therefore to the OP, keep asking questions!

Comment: so you wrote a 600-character comment to explain why you're too lazy to explain a few lines of code and improve your answer for future visitors, who may not have commenting privileges? Cute. And please remember, not all programmers are in the software industry.

Comment: My character count was actually 800, but SO limits it to 600. That's why I truncated it down to 600. I've learned a ton from SO over the years. I've started posting now to help the novice guys. Those of us posting answers are getting nothing out of it (except that we were able to help others). If you feel my answer needs to be annotated, feel free to edit it. Or add an answer of your own. We would love to see it.

Comment: With 52,000+ reputation clearly Matt could have edited your answer had he wanted. It's great that you are posting to help the novices - most of us are. Matt was just trying to help you make your answers more generally useful, I think. Try and ignore the snarkiness your defensive reply engendered. Not really a big enough issue to waste more typing on.

Comment: @holden I'm not here for points. Downvote me to zero, it doesn't matter. I learned a lot in SO. I feel I need to post answers, because I've learned a ton. Lemme also tell you a story. I attended an expensive CS program. One day I told the prof I was having issues getting ssh keys from AWS using his instructions. He said "Google it". I was furious. Paying high tuition, he owes his time, right? But then I saw light. My snippet introduced "enumerate". I left it to the OP to investigate it. There's even a PEP on it. Anything more complicated I would've elaborated. See my other posts as proof.

Comment: No problem! Be sure to take a look at enumerate in python docs. Furthermore, I did something unusual with the string slicing. Note that I went past the last element... little known, but you can do this in Python!